# Facing issues while calling Azure cognitive API's

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, ovh

I have small test app, which I am using to call the Azure cognitive(TTS) API. I have deployed this app currently on VPS (HostGator), where it is working fine as expected. The voice files are also converted and able to download them.

However, I am facing issues with OVH France dedicated server. I have created VPS out of this and deployed the application, everything works fine like the dashboard and login/ logout function. The problem is with Azure API, every time the API is called, the request is pending and times out after ~2 minutes. There are no error messages as well.
I have tried disabling the ddos protection on OVH IP as well, but I am not sure what is wrong at this point. This is problem with Azure and not with other provider, the Google auth and captcha API work fine.

Is there I am missing something? Is it something related to EU location or GDPR or something that needs to be done/ configure on Azure?
Because I have tried the same thing on DigitalOcean and Vultr droplet, everything works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is common in cloud platforms and especially with EU region. It is not because of the platform like azure, GCP or digital ocean. In other cloud service providers also the EU region is facing issue. Try to avoid operating on those availability zones and re-map to new region.